# Undefined resolve property in controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, angular-ui-router, undefined, resolve

I have resolve in my route .state where I return a list (data from server), which is defined when I console.log it in the .state route, but in controller it is undefined when I console.log it. I'm working with ionic 1 and AngularJS.

**Route**

```
.state('app', {
  url: '/app',
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
  controller: 'AppCtrl',
  controllerAs: 'appcn',
  resolve: {
    notificationsResolve: function ($http) {
      $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = "Basic MzEwMzIzOjEyMw==";
      return $http.get("http://192.168.178.24:8090/notifications/")
              .then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
              });
    }
  }
})
```

**Controller**

angular.module('starter.controllers', ['appServiceAPI'])

```
.controller('AppCtrl', ['notificationService', function($ionicModal, $timeout, notificationsResolve,
                                                        notificationService) {

  var vm = this;

  console.log("resolve: " + notificationsResolve);

  vm.notifications = notificationsResolve;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.controller('AppCtrl', ['notificationService', 
                function($ionicModal, $timeout, notificationsResolve, notificationService) {
```

You forgot 3 of your 4 arguments in the array. It should be

```
.controller('AppCtrl', ['$ionicModal', '$timeout', 'notificationsResolve', 'notificationService', 
                function($ionicModal,   $timeout,   notificationsResolve,   notificationService) {
```

Or better, you should just use the basic syntax, without this ugly and bug-prone repetition, and use [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) to make your code minifiable for you.

Comment: exactly this... this is the problem and much better off using a plugin to do this task rather than messing it up 1000 times and being confused every time.

Answer (score 0):

Params and their names must match

```
// this is wrong
.controller('AppCtrl', 
  ['notificationService', 
  function($ionicModal, $timeout, notificationsResolve, notificationService)

// this correct
.controller('AppCtrl', 
  ['$ionicModal', '$timeout', 'notificationsResolve', 'notificationService',
  function($ionicModal, $timeout, notificationsResolve, notificationService)
```